# for loop with cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, cell-array

I'm new to MATLAB and I'm having problem with a for loop in a cell array. I have a 52x52 cell array `B`. In every cell, there is a 51x51 matrix. For every cell of the first row of B, I want to calculate the trace and I want the trace-elements in a vector (and smooth them with a spline). The variables `dbmus` and `cs` may be overwritten every time, `SQED` and `ddbmus` not. I have the following line of code, but I keep getting this error: `In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.`

```
X = 1:51;                 
xx = linspace(1,51,250);  
SQED = zeros(1,52);
dbmus = zeros(1,52);
ddbmus = zeros(1,52);
for i = 1:52
    SQED(i) = sum(diag(B{1,i}));
    dbmus = transpose(diag(B{1,i}));
    cs = spline(X,[dbmus(1),dbmus,dbmus(end)]);      
    ddbmus(i) = ppval(cs,xx);                        
end
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: That means that one of the lines within your for loop is attempting to place a vector into an element. What line gives the error? It's either the first or last statement inside the for loop.

Comment: use `dbstop if error` and check the sizes/types of your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ppval evaluates your spline at all points in `xx`.  That produces a vector.  You then try to store the vector in `ddbmus(i)`, which is a scalar.

You probably want to store the full vector in rows (or columns) of a matrix.  If so:

```
ddbmus = zeros(52, 250);
for i = 1:52
    % ... existing code
    ddbmus(i, :) = ppval(cs,xx);
end
```